# SQL: Select Rows Where Their Relation Column Is Empty

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have two tables named **Post** and **Tag** which they have a many-to-many relation between each other.

How can I select Posts where it has no Tag attached to it?

Something like `posts.where(post => post.tags.length === 0 )`

Comment: There are multiple ways to implement this.  Check `NOT EXISTS` `LEFT JOIN` `INNER QUERY` `CORRELATED SUBQUERY`

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You can use`NOT IN` in filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT post.* 
   FROM post LEFT OUTER JOIN tag
   ON post.<link_field> = tag.<link_field>
   WHERE tag.<any_field> IS NULL;
```

The LEFT OUTER JOIN will yield all posts and NULL results for tag fields when there is no related (linked) tag.
So if you filter with:

```
WHERE tag.<any_field> IS NULL
```

you will get the posts without tags only.

This is tested with PostgreSQL, but should work with any reasonable database system as it is pure SQL standard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OUTER JOIN not implemented in MySQL

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev The FULL OUTER JOIN is not supported by MySql. A LEFT OUTER JOIN is supported.

Comment: (where any non-nullable field is null)

Comment: I just used a LEFT OUTER JOIN in MySqli and it worked just fine. Showed a customer list of all customers (main table) with the count of orders for each customer (from the orders table), even if the customer did not have any orders. PHP version 7.3.33 , MySQL version 5.7.23-23. So this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Using LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.post_id = posts.id
WHERE tags.id IS NULL;
```

Using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tags.post_id = posts.id
);
```

Using NOT IN:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE posts.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM tags
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The 2 tables do not (or they should not) have a direct many-to-many relationship.
You must create another table for this purpose:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_tags(
  post_id INT, 
  tag_id INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES posts(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(id)
)
```

where you save all the posts and tags that are related.
With this table you can track all posts that have no tags attached to them:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN posts_tags pt
ON pt.post_id = p.id
WHERE pt.post_id IS NULL
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM posts_tags WHERE post_id = p.id)
```